# Time until absorption markov chain with weights

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I have a markov chain with one absorbing state. In each state i, t<sub>i</sub> seconds must elapse before moving to the next state. Starting at t<sub>0</sub> what is the expected time to reach t<sub>3</sub>?

t<sub>0</sub> = 5,
t<sub>1</sub> = 10,
t<sub>2</sub> = 15,
t<sub>3</sub> = 20

My transition matrix looks like this:

\begin{bmatrix}3/4&1/4&0&0\\4/5&0&1/5&0\\6/7&0&0&1/7\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I know that I need to solve this as a system of linear equations namely each equation dictated by:

$$h_i = \sum_{k=0}^Np_{ik}h_k+1$$

But I'm not sure how the "+ 1" or the time/weight affects it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the expected time or the probability distribution?

Comment: I'm looking for the expected time. Will edit to reflect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The +1 in the equation for state $i$ would be replaced by $t_i$, in which case this system of equations is exactly what you would get using first transition analysis. Intuitively, you can think of it as "expected hitting time from state i is equal to time spent in the state i + expected hitting time from the state you visit from state i (which is given by the summation term)"